Tips for custom vue components
I'm using vs code. I wanted to find out if there is a way to create hints for a custom vue component.
Example: I have a component QLabelValuesItem and when I hover over it I want to see what it expects in props

I see that library components have such hints
Example:


You can document your component using JSDOC.
In your case, with your QLabelValuesItem  component, you could do something like this:
<template>
  <!-- Your QLabelValuesItem template-->
</template>

<script>
/**
 * The description of your component.
 * 
 * @prop {String} title - The description of your prop.
 * @prop {String} text - The description of your prop.
 * @emits emitExample - The description of your emit.
 */
export default {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  emits: ['emitExample'],
}
</script>

Now when you hovers over your component in an editor, you can check out the info about it.

Hi, yes, I thought so too, I tried adding similar constructions, but it didn't work.
Have you tried to reproduce it? Maybe you need to install some libraries in vs-code?
